# Hatch pattern with markdown

Tags: markdown

Is it possible to create a hatch pattern in an area with markdown?

I would like to hatch half of a table.

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

How would I hatch Column 2 please?

Comment: You can use html in markdown to create the pattern you want.